# adding bootstrap theme to electron app with node dependencies

Tags: node.js, sass, dependencies, electron

I have an electron app(electron-boilerplate) that uses less and node to manage dependencies. I want to add a bootstrap theme based in sass. When I try to add the bootstrap theme to the project and write "gulp build" to all of the files  in the build folders, I realize only packages I install via npm will build in that folder. In this case how can I drop in a theme with its own set of SASS, imgs, and js and have it compile with the build but also replace the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah dug deeper and looks like I have to declare it in the tasks/build.js file.

Comment: this explains absolutely nothing